# Scientific Calculator

Tags: performance, beginner, c, calculator

I finished this code a few minutes ago. It started off as an explanation of a basic calculator in C to a friend. Then we decided to take it further and I made this. Please tell me where I can make changes, no matter how small, you think needs to be changed/made better. Also I'm new to the C language, I've self studied it for around 4-5 months.

I did not get any errors and it works exactly like I expected it to. I am just looking for help improving myself and the way I code. Also this is my biggest code in C yet.

And please feel free to share your own similar calculators or creations.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define pi 3.14159265359

float add(float a, float b);
float sub(float a, float b);
float mult(float a, float b);
float divide(float a, float b);
float sqroot(float a);
float power(float a, float b);
float sine(float a);
float cosine(float a);
float tangent(float a);
float logarithm(float a);


int main() {

    float a, b, val;
    int op;
    char choice;
    
    printf("to choose an operation, enter the number of the operation 1)+  2)-  3)*  4)/  5)power  6)sqrt  7)sin  8)cos  9)tan  10)log(base 10) : ");
    scanf("%d", &op);

    if (op > 0 && op < 6) {
        printf("enter first number: ");
        scanf("%f", &a);

        printf("enter second number: ");
        scanf("%f", &b);

    }
    else if (op > 5 && op < 11) {
        printf("enter a number: ");
        scanf("%f", &a);

    }

    switch(op) {
        case 1: val = add(a, b);      break;
        case 2: val = sub(a, b);      break;
        case 3: val = mult(a, b);     break;
        case 4: val = divide(a, b);   break;
        case 5: val = power(a, b);    break;
        case 6: val = sqroot(a);      break;
        case 7: val = sine(a);        break;
        case 8: val = cosine(a);      break;
        case 9: val = tangent(a);     break;
        case 10: val = logarithm(a);  break;

        default: printf("invalid operator..."); break;

    }

    if (op > 0 && op < 11) {
        printf("answer is: %f", val);
        
        getchar();

        printf("\ncontinue? (y/n) ");
        scanf("%c", &choice);
        
        if (choice == 'y') {
            main();
        }
        else if (choice == 'n') {
            printf("ok cool bye");            
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

float add(float a, float b) {
    return a + b;
}

float sub(float a, float b) {
    return a - b;
}

float mult(float a, float b) {
    return a * b;
}

float divide(float a, float b) {
    return a / b;
}

float sqroot(float a) {
    return sqrt(a);
}

float power(float a, float b) {
    return pow(a, b);
}

float sine(float a) {
    return sin(a * pi / 180);
}

float cosine(float a) {
    return cos(a * pi / 180);
}

float tangent(float a) {
    return tan(a * pi / 180);
}

float logarithm(float a) {
    return log10(a);
}





/*if (op == '+') {
        printf("\n %f + %f = %f", a, b, a + b);
    }
    else if (op == '-') {
        printf("\na - b = %f", a - b);
    }
    else if (op == '-' && a < b) {
        printf("\nb - a = %f", b - a);
    }
    else if (op == '*') {
        printf("\na * b = %f", a * b);
    }
    else if (op == '/') {
        printf("\na / b = %f", a / b);
    }*/
```

Answer (score 8):

**Imprecise pi**

Use at [least](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289669/29485) `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` significant digits. `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG` is commonly 17.

**Check input return values**

Detect input success

```
// scanf("%f", &a);
if (scanf("%f", &a) != 1) {
  Handle_bad_input();  // TBD code
}
```

**Minor: Use correct sentence casing**

```
// printf("enter first number: ");
printf("Enter first number: ");
```

**Avoid naked magic numbers**

Document constants like 1,5,6... as to what they represent.

```
// if (op > 0 && op < 6) {
#define OP2_MIN 1
#define OP2_MAX 5
if (op >= OP2_MIN && op < OP2_MAX) {
```

Even better, derive these values from the length of the function array (see next).

**Rather than a `switch`, consider a table look up**

```
if (op >= OP2_MIN && op < OP2_MAX) {
  float (*ops2)() = { add,  sub, ... , power}; 
  float f() = ops2[op - OP2_MIN];
  val = f(a, b);
  ...
```

**Simplify**

```
// getchar();
printf("\ncontinue? (y/n) ");
// scanf("%c", &choice);
scanf(" %c", &choice);  // Space added to consume prior white-space.
```

**Avoid re-entrant `main()`**

Re-entrant `main()` is often considered an undesirable coding style.  Re-work code.

If staying with recursion:
`if (choice == 'y') { main();` should have been `if (choice == 'y') { return  main();`

**Improve degree arguments**

Since code is using *degrees*, reduce the range before calling.  This will improve the results of large degree arguments as `pi` only approximates the irrational `π`.
More details: [Sin and Cos give unexpected results for well-known angles](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31502120/2410359).

```
a = fmodf(a, 360); // add this reduction.
sin(a * pi / 180);
```

**`float` or `double`**

Code is using `float` arguments with `double` functions.

Use `sqrtf, powf, ...` with `float` arguments or ...
even better, use `double a, b, ...`

**More common to end output with a line-feed**

```
// printf("answer is: %f", val);
printf("answer is: %f\n", val);
```

**It is *floating* point**

`printf("answer is: %f", val);` prints with a fixed precision format - worthless for tiny results and noisy for large ones.

Use `%g` to print general *floating point* output.

```
// printf("answer is: %f", val);
printf("Answer is: %g", val);
```

If you go with `double` variables (recommended), use:

```
printf("Answer is: %.*g", DBL_DIG, val);
```

**Detect common issues**

Consider detecting and printing a warning with common problems.

- Division by zero.
- Negative `sqrt()`, `logarithm()` calls.

---

Following is some code tossed together to illustrate some of the above ideas and a few more (structure driven function/key, re-organized flow, a zero-arg function call).

This *illustrative code* compiles, but is **not tested**.  If I reviewed it like OP's code, I likely find 10+ issues with it, but without spending too much more time, I wanted to present OP with some real alternative code.

````
#include <errno.h>
#include <float.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DEGREES_IN_A_CIRCLE 360.0
// pi/180 --> 0.01745...
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(d) ((d)*0.01745329251994329576923690768489)

double add(double a, double b) {
  return a + b;
}

double sub(double a, double b) {
  return a - b;
}

double mult(double a, double b) {
  return a * b;
}

double divide(double a, double b) {
  return a / b;
}

double sqroot(double a) {
  return sqrt(a);
}

double power(double a, double b) {
  return pow(a, b);
}

double sine_d(double a_degree) {
  a_degree = fmod(a_degree, DEGREES_IN_A_CIRCLE);
  return sin(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(a_degree));
}

double cosine_d(double a_degree) {
  a_degree = fmod(a_degree, DEGREES_IN_A_CIRCLE);
  return cos(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(a_degree));
}

double tangent_d(double a_degree) {
  a_degree = fmod(a_degree, DEGREES_IN_A_CIRCLE);
  return tan(DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(a_degree));
}

double logarithm10(double a) {
  return log10(a);
}

double now(void) {
  return (double) time(0);
}

typedef struct {
  union {
    double (*f0)(void);
    double (*f1)(double a);
    double (*f2)(double a, double b);
  } f;
  unsigned n;
  const char *token;
} func;

// Maximum argument count
#define ARG_N 2

const func operator[] = { //
    { {0}, 0, "exit"}, //
        { .f.f2 = add, 2, "add"}, //
        { .f.f2 = sub, 2, "sub"}, //
        { .f.f2 = mult, 2, "mul"}, //
        { .f.f2 = divide, 2, "div"}, //
        { .f.f1 = sqroot, 1, "sqrt"}, //
        { .f.f2 = power, 2, "pow"}, //
        { .f.f1 = sine_d, 1, "sin"}, //
        { .f.f1 = cosine_d, 1, "cos"}, //
        { .f.f1 = tangent_d, 1, "tan"}, //
        { .f.f1 = logarithm10, 1, "log10"}, //
        { .f.f0 = now, 0, "now"}, //
    };

int operator_n = sizeof operator / sizeof operator[0];

int main(void) {
  for (;;) {
    printf("Choose an operation");
    for (int i = 0; i < operator_n; i++) {
      printf(", %s", operator[i].token);
    }
    printf(": ");
    char buf[100];
    if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
      break;
    }
    buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential trailing \n

    int op = operator_n;
    while (op-- > 0) {
      if (strcmp(buf, operator[op].token) == 0) {
        break;
      }
    }

    if (op < 0) {
      printf("Operation not found\n");
      continue;
    }
    if (op == 0) {
      break;
    }

    double arg[ARG_N];
    unsigned a;
    for (a = 0; a < operator[op].n && a < ARG_N; a++) {
      printf("Enter a number: ");
      if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) {
        break;
      }
      char *endptr;
      errno = 0;
      arg[a] = strtod(buf, &endptr);
      if (buf == endptr || errno || endptr[0] != '\n') {
        printf("Bad input\n");
        break;
      }
    }
    double val = NAN;
    if (a == operator[op].n) {
      switch (a) {
        case 0:
          val = operator[op].f.f0();
          break;
        case 1:
          val = operator[op].f.f1(arg[0]);
          break;
        case 2:
          val = operator[op].f.f2(arg[0], arg[1]);
          break;
      }
    }
    printf("answer is: %.*g", DBL_DIG, val);
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you maybe explain the first half of your answer a little simpler? Or maybe provide a source from where I can understand what you're saying easier? Quite a lot of what you told me literally flew over my head. And why is it that `scanf("%f ", &a);` will give no visible output and wont print the printf statement before it but a space before %f works? I don't quite understand it. And the 3rd and 4th bold pointers don't make any sense to me :D. I'm gonna look into them myself too but I would love it if you can provide some additional help? Thank you so much again!

Comment: @ThePowerHex_YT Let us start with `scanf("%f ", &a);`.  That obliges user to type a number, some 0 or more spaces and then something else.  Drop the following `" "` so `scanf()` will return once some non-numeric input follows the number.  The "space before" is a red herring.  It is the "space after" that cause you woe.

Comment: @ThePowerHex_YT What is unclear about "// printf("enter first number: ");
printf("Enter first number: ");"?

Comment: @ThePowerHex_YT What is unclear about "Avoid naked magic numbers"?  Code that uses `if (op > 0 && op < 6)` lacks clarity.  Why `6`?  what is so special about 6?  Code should convey a constant as a phrase and not a bare `6` to establish some meaning.

Comment: i meant the "Avoid naked magic numbers" portion, and I see that what you are saying makes so much more sense that I feel dumb for not doing that on my own.... Also why does the space after %f cause me woe again? My brain is probably not braining enough to understand what you said regarding that.

Comment: @ThePowerHex_YT What do you think a `" "` after  `"%f"` does?  Hint: it refers to 0 or more _white-spaces_.

Comment: I think it might be doing something like what getchar() does?

Comment: also is the table look up called table lookup in all sources of information for the thing? I want to know more about what it is and does, I don't want to mix it up with something similar sounding.

Comment: @ThePowerHex_YT The `" "` is _bad_.  It says to search for 0 or more trailing whitespaces (including `'\n'`) until a non-white space is found.  Why have you considered coding that way?

Comment: does 
```.
if (scanf("%f", &a) != 1) {
  Handle_bad_input();  // TBD code
}
```
mean that the if statement is checking whether the scanf statement is true or not? like whether its 0 or 1? or is that referring to something else?

Comment: @ThePowerHex_YT `scanf()` returns the number or successfully converted specifiers.  With `scanf("%f", ...)`, that may be 0, 1 or EOF.  Only a return of  1 is OK for your code.  Returning `!= 1` deserves other handling.  What do you want to do if user input is not a textual number?

Comment: I want the user to know what they did wrong and end the execution there, so if i was testing it, I would have to click on the run button again instead of getting an option to continue through the same program.

Comment: @ThePowerHex_YT A r[easonable approach](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/289712/scientific-calculator/289715?noredirect=1#comment577176_289715).  So if `scanf("%f", &a) !=1`, simply quit with an error message as to why like "Input does not convert to a `float`.".  A key to good programming is to validate inputs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151648/discussion-between-thepowerhex-yt-and-chux-reinstate-monica).